# Can't sync data

Tags: samsung

I keep geting a message like this "Can't sync data; Not enough space on your phone".  I added extended memory. How can I take from the main memory and put on extended memory? Can Someone please help me? Samsung SM-J320W8

Answer (score 0):

Have you moved all of your pictures over to the SD card?

It works for other things too like videos and documents, but not apps, I believe.

If not, try this:
1 go to your file app.
2 select your photos
3 hold down on them and hit more(or 3 dots if you use most 3rd party file explorers)

4 select move (not copy)
5 navagate to your SD card and select ok